# How to join audio files of different formats in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to join multiple audio files in ffmpeg. I am using the following command:

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i myfile.txt -c copy output.mp3
```

Where `myfile.txt` contains audio file paths. I am able to join the mp3 audio, but is it possible to join together audio of another format (like avi, wav, m4a, etc.)?

Comment: From the [concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1): "All input files must have the same streams (same codecs, same time base, etc)."

Comment: @Amit Chandra- you possibly mean "join" not "merge"? Join would put them one after another. Merge would "mix" streams together. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Rajib I want to join audios. How can i achieve that??

Comment: As explained by @LordNeckbeard you will have to transcode and use the concat `filter` rather than the demuxer if your inputs have different codecs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.wav -i input2.mp3 -i input3.aac -filter_complex 'concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]' -map '[a]' <encoding options> output.mp3
```

Here we are outputting to mp3 from 3 different audio codec inputs. You will have to input the mp3 encoding parameters. I'm assuming your input files are audio only.

Good parameters for mp3 might 256 kbps. Then use this:

```
-codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 256k
```

But this is considered wasteful for mp3 and you might want to use instead: `-q:a 3`

See [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) and also [this](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=LAME#Recommended_encoder_settings).

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks a lot!